# Why the fourth homology of the cofibre of Moore space $H_4(C) = 0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Why the fourth homology of the cofibre of Moore space (of dimension 2) equals $0$ i.e. $H_4(C) = 0$?

Could anyone explain this to me, please? I think it is related to the construction of Moore space of dimension 2 and that there are no cells in the fourth dimension, but why there are cells in the third dimension?

**Definition:**

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $n$ an integer $\geq 2.$ A Moore space of type $(G,n)$ is $1-$connected, $CW-$complex $X$ such that:

$$ \widetilde{H}_i(X) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & if \, i \neq n, \\
      G &  if   i = n. 
   \end{cases} $$

Comment: Please tell us your definition of Moore space.

Comment: @ConnorMalin ok I will edit my question with the definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "the cofiber of Moore space"?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the long exact sequence in homology?

Comment: @EricWofsey I mean the cofibre of maps (universal quantifiers ) between Moore spaces.

Comment: @JHF I think I get this information from my professor and my professor said it is related to the construction of Moore spaces but I do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the long exact sequence in homology as @JHF said: given a map $f: X \to X$ with cofiber $C$, it will look like
$$
\dots \to H_4(X) \xrightarrow{f_*} H_4(X) \to H_4(C) \to H_3(X) \to \dots
$$
You know from the definition of $X$ that its homology groups in this range are zero, so the long exact sequence looks like
$$
\dots \to 0 \to 0 \to H_4(C) \to 0 \to \dots
$$

Comment: How do I know from the definition of $X$ that its homology groups in this range are zero ? what in the definition tell me that?

Comment: You gave the definition: $\widetilde{H}_i(X)=0$ unless $i=n$. In this case $n=2$ since you said it is a Moore space "of dimension 2".

Comment: What about $H_1(C)$ in this sequence? what is it equal? is it $0$ or $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Happy: 0 also: use the long exact sequence for reduced homology, in which the only nonzero entry for the Moore space is in dimension 2.

Comment: And why we should use the long exact sequence for reduced homology in that case?

Comment: Because it works? Because the Moore space is defined in terms of its reduced homology? Because 0-dimensional homology and maps between 0-dimensional homology groups are easy to understand? I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: I mean why the ordinary long exact sequence for homology does not work if we are asking about $H_1(C)$?

Comment: The ordinary sequence works, because as I just said, maps between 0-dimensional homology groups are easy to understand. But the reduced sequence is simpler.

Comment: but the ordinary sequence has $0$ before $H_1(C)$ and $\mathbb Z$ after it .... why should we conclude from this that $H_1(C) = 0$?

Comment: I will say this one last time: maps between 0-dimensional homology groups are easy to understand. If you don't understand this, please ask a new question on this site rather than just commenting on someone else's old question.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry about that.